# Lose window.history.state after page refresh in Firefox Quantum

Tags: javascript, firefox, history.js

I do not know if a problem in the history library or browser, but ...

I am working on Firefox Quantum 57.0.4 64 bit, and when I select the url and press enter, after updating the page I can not get the history.location.state. After investigating, I discovered that window.history.state is null.

Does anyone have this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure whether or not this is a bug in Firefox, because in other browsers (i.e. Chrome/IE11/Edge) it works fine using `window.history.replaceState(null, null, url);`.
The fix for FF seems to be using `window.history.pushState(null, null, url);`, as described here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API
When using `pushState` you can press F5 and everything is fine.

Edit: Is a firefox bug and not fixed yet: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1422334

Edit2: We currently use `pushState` instead of `replaceState` in FF (only in FF) until the mentioned bug is fixed.